# What is going wrong in this target date calculater?

Tags: android, date

I write this code for my project some time ago, It should calculate the target date the user probably achieve his diet goal. but in testing the application I find out that whatever the goal entered the target date always be one month greater the date created.

this is the code

```
    public String calcTD(SQLiteDatabase db){
    String date = null;
    myDataBase = db;
    Cursor c = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM USER", null);
    if (c!= null){
        if (c.moveToFirst()){
          String cdate = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("CreatedDate"));              
          String type = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("GoalType"));              
          if (type == "Maintain Weight")
                date = cdate;
          else{               
            int rate = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Rate"));
            float gw = c.getFloat(c.getColumnIndex("GoalWeight"));
            float cw = getCW(db); //get current weight
            float w = 0; int days = 0;
            if (type == "Lose Weight")
                 w = cw - gw;
            else if (type == "Gain Weight")
                w = gw - cw;                
            switch (rate){
            case 0: // the rate 250g/week
                days = Math.round(w * 7 * 4); 
                break;
            case 1: //the rate 500g/week
                days = Math.round(w * 7 * 2); 
                break;
            case 2://the rate 750g/week
                days = Math.round(w * 7 * (4/3)) ;
                break;
            case 3:the rate 1kg/week
                days = Math.round(w * 7);
                break;
            }
            int y, m, d;
                            // the currentDate format (YYYYMMDD)
            y = Integer.parseInt(cdate.substring(0,4));
            m = Integer.parseInt(cdate.substring(4,6));
            d = Integer.parseInt(cdate.substring(6,8));             
            GregorianCalendar  i = new GregorianCalendar(y, m, d);
            i.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, days);
            date = AllCmnMtd.getDate(i);    // this will convert the date to a string with format (yyyymmdd)            

            }               
        }
    }
    return date;    
}
```

Sorry for being such annoying person, but my project defense within two weeks, and I am facing many error while testing the application!! :(.

Thank you and best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java's Calendar class uses 0 based indexes for months. Ex. 0 is January and 11 is December.

Subtract one from m before you put into the Calendar object.

Comment: @MisterSquonk Helps when I got bit by the same bug about a week ago ... :-)

Comment: thank you for drawing my attention for that :) , I also has the problem for not calculating a thing, but I solve it by changing the method to compare strings to (equals), now every thing is working!:)